# How to add a service reference to .asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service-reference

The team I am working on is using an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application using `net46` framework and we are needing to add a service reference to an `.asmx` legacy service that is maintained by a 3rd party.

We have not discovered a way to "Add Service Reference..." as we would have in the past. i.e. Right-click on the references under the project file and click "Add Service Reference"

The docs didn't seem to have any help as I searched https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/search.html?q=service+reference&check_keywords=yes&area=default and got no results.

Has anyone done this yet and/or can provide documentation so that we can connect?

Would spinning up a separate solution not in ASP.NET Core 1.0 and providing a WebAPI be viable here if no one has done the above? Possible workaround: we are discussing.

Edit: Added what our targeted framework is.

Comment: You should be able to use the command line tool svcutil.exe to generate the necessary files (same ones the old wizard generated).

Answer (score 5):

There is a [WCF Connected Services Extension on Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3b3666e-a928-4136-9346-22e30c949c08), which allows you to create .NET Core compatible WCF proxy classes. It should work with WCF and .aspx webservices.

It adds the missing "Add Service Reference" menu. Also check out the blog where [it was announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/) for a short tutorial on it's usage.

Comment: There is also a great post here that shows how to use it: http://tattoocoder.com/asp-net-core-getting-clean-with-soap/

Comment: This looked promising but ran into a problem that our targeted framework is "net46" and this tool told me we needed to be targeting "netcoreapp1.3". I should have mentioned this before most likely. We are going to try having a separate project that will target this on Monday.

Comment: @DustinHarrell, search for `svcutil` under Visual Studio installation folder, and you will find the .NET Core compatible version (part of this preview extension). Then use the command line parameters to generate a C# file (instead of doing so in IDE). Then it does not matter which target framework you use. However, note that this is preview bits, and I already hit some problems.

Comment: Looks like this would work for others, but not our situation. We ended up creating an old WebApi and call it as a wrapper for the .asmx service.